# Get value of two instances of a secondary table

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, query-performance

I have two tables, users and permissions.  Users have a username.  Permissions have a name (e.g. cards, pages, players) and a type (e.g. read only, read/write) and a foreign key relationship to users.  Both tables have an basic integer primary key.

For various reasons I would like to query all user to see the status of their cards permission and pages permission at the same time.  My ideal output would be something like...

```
|------------------------------------------------|
| Username | Cards Permission | Pages Permission |
|------------------------------------------------|
|   Bob    |   Read / Write   |   Read Only      |
```

I have already thought of two ways I can do this but neither is ideal.

First, I can query twice, each time collecting User.Id, User.Username, Permission.Type.  The first for cards permission and the second for pages permission.  I can then correlate the two queries in the application.

```
SELECT u.Id, u.Username, p.Type 
  FROM User u 
  INNER JOIN Permission p ON p.UserId = u.Id
  WHERE p.Name = '?';
```

Second, I can query once, collecting User.Id, User.Username, Permission.Name, Permission.Type.  The query would join the permissions table and take all permissions whose name is Cards or Pages (essentially I'd get 2 times as many records, each User.Id would show up twice).  I could then correlate the results in the application.

```
SELECT u.Id, u.Username, p.Name, p.Type 
  FROM User u 
  INNER JOIN Permission p ON p.UserId = u.Id
  WHERE p.Name = 'cards' or p.Name = 'pages';
```

Is there any query I can use that would give me the output I desire?  I'm asking mainly for my own edification.  If I JOIN the permissions table twice I end up with a cross product and run out of memory (there are 1,000,000 users and 10,000,000 permissions).

UPDATE: Detailed Schema

```
User
----
Id bigint not null identity primary key
Username varchar(64) not null

Permission
----------
Id bigint not null identity primary key
UserId bigint not null foreign key
Name varchar(64) not null
Type int not null
-Index non-clustered non-unique Id, UserId, Name
```

Comment: SQL server 2k16 enterprise in production.

Comment: Added some details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are just trying to pivot some data.

```
select
    u.Id
  , u.Username
  , [Cards Permission]  =max(case when p.Name='Cards'   then p.Type else null end)
  , [Pages Permission]  =max(case when p.Name='Pages'   then p.Type else null end)
  --, [Players Permission]=max(case when p.Name='Players' then p.Type else null end)
  from user u 
    inner join Permission p ON p.UserId = u.Id
  group by u.Id, u.username;
```

or if we want the name of the type for `type integer`, something like:

```
select
    u.Id
  , u.Username
  , [Cards Permission]  =max(case when p.Name='Cards'   then t.Name else null end)
  , [Pages Permission]  =max(case when p.Name='Pages'   then t.Name else null end)
  --, [Players Permission]=max(case when p.Name='Players' then t.Name else null end)
  from user u 
    inner join Permission p ON p.UserId = u.Id
    inner join [Type] t ON p.Type = t.Id
  group by u.Id, u.username;
```

---

If your nonclustered index on permissions is `(Id, UserId, Name)`, it's not doing you any favors. unique nonclustered `(UserId, Name, Type)` or nonclustered `(UserId, Name) include (Type)` would be more useful.